# NameError: name 'INPUT' is not defined

Tags: python, input, syntax-error, undefined, filenames

I am getting an error when I try to run this simple script:

```
assert len(sys.argv) == 2, '[USAGE] $ python %s img_6.jpg' % (os.path.basename(__file__), INPUT)
INPUT = sys.argv[1]
assert os.path.isfile(INPUT), '%s not found' % INPUT
```

the error I am getting is:

```
assert len(sys.argv) == 2, '[USAGE] $ python %s img_6.jpg' % (os.path.basename(__file__), INPUT)
NameError: name 'INPUT' is not defined
```

I am running these scripts with Python 2.7.

```
**THANK A LOT **
```

Comment: I'm trying not to be snarky, but you give the answer in your title, I think

Comment: As the error message says, you are using the variable `INPUT` before you define it. And you cannot use `sys.argv[1]` in the error message, as you may not have it, if the assertion fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `INPUT` before you reference it.

```
INPUT = sys.argv[1]
assert len(sys.argv) == 2, '[USAGE] $ python %s img_6.jpg' % (os.path.basename(__file__), INPUT)
assert os.path.isfile(INPUT), '%s not found' % INPUT
```